# Getting count from two joined tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, count

I have 4 tables, each with a one-to-many relationship:

```
client -< inspection -< car -< issue
```

and I'm trying to select the name and the address of a client along with the count of the inspections and the count of the issues.

Here is what I have so far: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/e62ba/29/0

In the example above the result for `client._id = 1` should be:

```
 client_name    client_address   Inspection count   Issue count
 "John"         "1 Main street"  2                  3
```

and for `client._id = 2` it should be:

```
 client_name    client_address   Inspection count   Issue count
 "Jane"         "1 Wall street"  0                  0
```

Is it possible to achieve this result in one query, or do I have to use a subquery for issue count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT c.client_name, c.client_address,
       COUNT(DISTINCT i._id) AS "Inspection count",
       COUNT(DISTINCT iss._id) AS "Issue count"
FROM client c LEFT JOIN
     inspection i
     ON c._id = i.client_id LEFT JOIN
     (car ca INNER JOIN
      issue iss
      ON iss.car_id = ca._id
     )
     ON ca.inspection_id = i._id
WHERE c._id = 1;
```

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I was after. Thanks